# Confusion about Compact Set Example of Topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The compact set is defined in Topology as:

$K\subset X$ is Compact if K's every open cover has a finite subcover (ie, there exists a finite sub-collection for every open cover $\{G_\alpha\}$ that is also open cover of K).

An compact example is closed set $K=[0,1]$.

I think of three open sets: $G_1=(-0.1,0.4),G_2=(0.3,0.8), G_3=(0.7,1.2)$, then $K\subset G_1\cup G_2\cup G_3=(-0.1,1.2)$, so $\{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha=1}^3$ is an open cover of K. However, any sub-collection union of $\{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha=1}^3$ cannot cover K, which implies non-compact.

Could someone tell me where I got wrong? Thanks.

Comment: But $\{G_\alpha \}_{\alpha =1,2,3}$ is already a finite sub-cover of $[0,1]$...

Comment: Non *com*pact, not *im*pact

Comment: @Surb Thanks for your answer. But from the definition $\{G_\alpha \}_{\alpha =1,2,3}$ is also an open cover, and the sub-collection of it cannot cover K.

Answer (score 3):

A sub-collection is not necessarily a *strict* sub-collection. $\{G_1,G_2,G_3\}$ is a sub-collection of $\{G_1,G_2,G_3\}$. Collection here is really synonymous with set, and a sub-collection is a subset. Every set is a subset of itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if sub-collection is not strictly sub, then as long as a set has open cover, then it is compact, which may not be true.

Comment: No, the subcover needs to be finite, too. If the original open cover is infinite, then you can't simply take the cover itself as the subcover.